# Should we add a platform tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

This question was just asked: [Can I download GPS so I can play Pokémon go?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/273185/108003).

It's actually a question about the platform, not the game. Therefore, it would make sense to add a platform tag. I don't see one for the iPod 6th generation. Would it just be iPod, or would we make one for each version? Should it be the iOS tag?

Comment: If we are going to tag it with a platform, I suggest [ios] and [hardware]

Comment: I'm on the fence about this.  Tagging for platform would be great to help separate and diagnose issues of the same game, but a part of me is worried that a new user would confuse a tag for one platform meaning it's not an answer for another. (Even if the issue itself isn't platform dependent.)